# Get files list after azure data factory copy activity

Tags: azure, copy, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

Is there a method that gives me the list of files copied in azure data lake storage after a copy activity in azure data factory? I have to copy data from a datasource and after i have to skip files based on a particular condition. Condition must check also file path and name with other data from sql database. any idea?

Answer (score 1):

As of now, there's no function to get the files list after a copy activity. You can however use a [get Metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity) activity or a [Lookup Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity) and chain a [Filter activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-filter-activity) to it to get the list of files based on your condition.

There's a workaround that you can check out [here](http://The%20solution%20was%20actually%20quite%20simple%20in%20this%20case.%20I%20just%20created%20another%20pipeline%20in%20Azure%20Data%20Factory,%20which%20was%20triggered%20by%20a%20Blob%20Created%20event,%20and%20the%20folder%20and%20filename%20passed%20as%20parameters%20to%20my%20notebook.%20Seems%20to%20work%20well,%20and%20a%20minimal%20amount%20of%20configuration%20or%20code%20required.%20Basic%20filtering%20can%20be%20done%20with%20the%20event,%20and%20the%20rest%20is%20up%20to%20the%20notebook.%20%20For%20anyone%20else%20stumbling%20across%20this%20scenario,%20details%20below:%20%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger).

"The solution was actually quite simple in this case. I just created another pipeline in Azure Data Factory, which was triggered by a Blob Created event, and the folder and filename passed as parameters to my notebook. Seems to work well, and a minimal amount of configuration or code required. Basic filtering can be done with the event, and the rest is up to the notebook.

For anyone else stumbling across this scenario, details below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger"

Comment: i don't have blob storage. only datalakestorage

Comment: You can use data lake storage too. Just that you won't be able to set up an event based trigger.